# How to get number of subscribers in a OpenTok session using REST API?

Tags: rest, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

How can I (or is there a way) get the number of subscribers connected and watching a publisher's stream, using OpenTok's REST API?

I know that I can count the connections on the server side by listening respective event, but if there is a REST API that I can query session information including the connected subscribers, I prefer to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenTok QA staff here.

As Carlos says, the answer is simple. You can't. There is no API to get the number of subscribers that are actually connected to a session. You have to handle it by yourself, using the events that the platform provides.

Answer (score 1):

Check the official API docs: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/ConnectionEvent.html, the `session` object dispatches some events that tell you when some one connects or disconnects from your session:

```
...

var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionID);

session.on('connectionCreated', function(e) {
  connectionCount++;
  ...
});

session.on('connectionDestroyed', function(e) {
  connectionCount--;
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, as I mention I'm looking for the REST API solution to get the number of the connected subscribers. So that means no API to get that info?

Comment: I saw the REST API and couldn't find any info about this, seems that only the client sdk has this functionality, maybe you should ask support team directly.